# selectively import "record sets" from one mysql instance to another

Tags: backup-restoration, mysql, database-restore

I have a mysql server hosting a production database, and routinely I make snapshots of it, which we can also use as a staging environment.

Sometime bad things happen, e.g. we delete a row (and all those connected to it through foreign keys) from production, and after fixing the bad code I procede to import the backed up data.

But, being a noob at ops, I am not sure of what the proper process would be.

As of now I have a script that does something like:

- get the row indexed  by key K (with mysqldump -w)
- get all the rows where row_key = K from a list of tables (again with mysqldump -w)
- insert all these rows in the prod db (with mysql )

This seems hackish, and is always open to some inconsistency both on the data finding part (e.g. the list of "related" tables in my database is incorrect) and on the data importing part (e.g. constraints get violated because the DBs have "diverged" and I must fix the `INSERT` code by hand ).

Is there a *proper* way to do this kind of things?

I can see related questions on SF, e.g.
[moving data from one MYSQL db to another](https://serverfault.com/questions/242980/moving-data-from-one-mysql-db-to-another)
but this seem related to merging whole dbs, or importing a whole backup, and not restoring a small "self contained" slice of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the way you've got it is pretty much the way it has to be done.  The *correct* solution to the problem is to never delete data -- flag it as inactive, or at worst move it to a "deleted" table.  Audit trails work well, too.

Comment: yeah flagging the data seems better, but I have an issue with that: basically, wherever I have an unique index on column C I need to change it to a multiple one. The "deleted_x" table seem to  present the same issues of importing from a backup (because I end up having a whole duplicate of a schema subset prefixed with "deleted_", when cross-table relations are involved). Or possibly there is something else I am not thinking of?

Comment: No, you're on the money.  It's a pest of a problem.